# Updating single row is slow with mixed types in pandas

Tags: pandas

A simple line of code `df.iloc[100] = df.iloc[500]` gets very slow on a large DataFrame with mixed types due to the fact that pandas copies the entire columns ([found it in the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1702)). What I don't get is why this behaviour is necessary and how to avoid it and force pandas to just update the relevant values if I am sure in advance that the dtypes are the same. When the DF is single-type then the copying doesn't take place and values are modified in-place.

I found a workaround that seems to have the desired effect but it works only on row numbers:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c].array[100] = df[c].array[500]
```

It is literally 1000x faster than `df.iloc[100] = df.iloc[500]`.

Here is how to reproduce the slowness of assignment:

```
import string
import itertools
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = list(itertools.product(range(200_000), string.ascii_uppercase))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['i', 'p'])
df['n1'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df['n2'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df['n3'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df['n4'] = np.random.randn(len(df))

print(
    timeit.timeit('df.loc[100] = df.loc[500]', number=100, globals=globals()) / 100
)

df_o = df.copy()

# Remove mixed types
for c in df_o.columns:
     df_o[c] = df_o[c].astype('object')
        
print(
    timeit.timeit('df_o.loc[100] = df_o.loc[500]', number=100, globals=globals()) / 100
)
```

This example alone shows 10x performance difference. I still don't fully understand why even with non-mixed types assigning a single row is quite slow.